# Refresh parent Iframe from another Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent, reload

i wanna refresh parent's iframe from another iframe with javascript.
more detail:

```
 ---------->iframe1(name:iframesubmit)
 |
 paraent
 |
 ---------->iframe2----->iframe3
```

iframe3 refresh iframe1.

i tried:

```
parent.window.iframesubmit.location.reload();
```

but refresh parent not parent's iframe.

Comment: are they on the same (sub)domain?

Comment: yes they are on the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be:

```
parent.parent.iframesubmit.location.reload(); //iframe2 > parent (grand parent)
```

ideally...

```
parent.parent.document.getElementById('iframesubmit').location.reload();
```